How Do I Connect to a Second IP Address When the First One Fails
I am trying to connect to one IP address.  If that one fails to connect, I need to connect to a different IP address.  I know the basic answer for this is to close the socket an instantiate another one.  This does not work for my situation.  I must use the same socket.  Below is my code showing that I close the socket and instantiate another one.  I was not able to put all of my code in the code section.
bool blnSuccess = false; // Wi-Fi connection status.
IPAddress hostLCSWiFi;   // LCS Wi-Fi IP address.
IPAddress hostBase3WiFi; // Base3 Wi-Fi IP address.

if (strConnectionType == "WiFiAPM")
{
    hostLCSWiFi = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.99.1");                    // IP Address for LCS WiFi module in Access Point mode.
    remoteEndPointLCSWiFiModule = new IPEndPoint(hostLCSWiFi, 50001); // Port for LCS WiFi module.

    result = clienteTCC.BeginConnect(remoteEndPointLCSWiFiModule, null, null);
    
    blnSuccess = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(500, true);

    if (!blnSuccess)
    {
        clienteTCC.Close();
        clienteTCC = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); // Instantiate socket for Base3 WiFi module.

        hostBase3WiFi = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.111.1");                     // IP Address for Base3 WiFi in Access Point mode.
        remoteEndPointBase3WiFiModule = new IPEndPoint(hostBase3WiFi, 50001); // Port for Base3 WiFi module.

        result = clienteTCC.BeginConnect(remoteEndPointBase3WiFiModule, null, null);

        blnSuccess = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(500, true);
    }

    clienteTCC.EndConnect(result);

I need to get rid of these two lines and replace them with something else.
clienteTCC.Close();
clienteTCC = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); // Instantiate socket for Base3 WiFi module.


" I must use the same socket. " - you can't. The other answers you've already found are true, even if you do not like this fact.

It appears that you need to return code with open socket A.  Create a new socket B, test the first IP address..  If it works, close B and then open A with that address.  If it doesnt, dispose B and open another socket C with the second IP address. If it works, close C, dispose it and open A with the second IP address.  If it doesnt work, dispose C and perform exception handling.

Very interesting.  I will try this and see what happens.  Thank you for this out of the box idea.
